# How to use .swift file in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have added (by drag n drop) a .swift file in my objective-C code, Now I want to use it into my Objective-C code. I tried importing like:

```
#import "MyProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

But file not found appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your target Build Settings and change `Define Module` to `Yes` and also you need to change `Product Module Name` to some value.
Now it will show the `YourProductModuleName` but if you click on it it shows `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)`, replace it with your module name and use it in import as in the example in your question.

Hope this help

Comment: Didn't work, I had to add the file manually (it may be because I may have previously clicked on No button in the dialogue that asks for making the bridge header automatically) and then File Not Found error vanishes. But I am still unable to see the swift class (ActionButton, for example) in code-completion list. I tried importing ActionButton.swift class in the MyProductModule-swift.h file, but didn't work.

Comment: Make your swift class inherited from NSObject and/or add @objc before the class word, for example: <at>objc class ActionButton : NSObject {...}

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't recognise my swift class in Objective C code. I tried doing the same into another old Object-C project, but didn't work. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The file is created automatically (talking about Xcode 6.3.2 here). But you won't see it, since it's in your Derived Data folder. After marking your swift class with @objc, compile, then search for Swift.h in your Derived Data folder. You should find the Swift header there.

I had the problem, that Xcode renamed my my-Project-Swift.h to my_Project_Swift.h Xcode doesn't like "." "-" etc. symbols. With the method above you can find the filename and import it to a Objective-C class.

And you should also need to change the target of your project to 10.9
Try this hope it helps.

Comment: Where to add @objc? And file doesn't create automatically, I had to add the file manually (because I read somewhere, if you press No when Xcode asks for bridging file, it won't ask again).